# Arduino - trying to get longitude and latitude from GPS with Arduino Uno and GSM and send the data to Firebase cloud but getting 0.0000

Tags: firebase, arduino, gps, arduino-uno, gsm

I am using Arduino Uno R3, GSM SIM 800 and GPS to get the latitude and longitude and send to the Firebase cloud, but end up I only can get 0.0000 for the location, was trying for TinyGPS++ code before and the GPS is working. Can someone helps me to see where is the error, I really tried for many solutions but still can't work

*** solved for the above problems
But now comes with the problem is about the http connect with the firebase. The status showing -2 for the http connection problem.

```
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800    
#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER 256
 
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>     
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>      
#include <TinyGPS++.h>    
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SerialMonitor Serial

#define ARDUINO_GPS_RX 11     
#define ARDUINO_GPS_TX 10    
TinyGPSPlus tinyGPS;    
SoftwareSerial ss(ARDUINO_GPS_TX , ARDUINO_GPS_RX);    
#define gpsPort ss
  
#define rxPin 3    
#define txPin 2    
SoftwareSerial sim800(txPin,rxPin);    
 
const char FIREBASE_HOST[]  = "my_firebase_host";    
const String FIREBASE_AUTH  = "my_firebase_auth";    
const String FIREBASE_PATH  = "/";    
const int SSL_PORT          = 443;    

char apn[]  = "internet";
char user[] = "";
char pass[] = "";
 
TinyGsm modem(sim800);    

TinyGsmClientSecure gsm_client_secure_modem(modem, 0);    
HttpClient http_client = HttpClient(gsm_client_secure_modem, FIREBASE_HOST, SSL_PORT);    
 
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;    
  
void setup()    
{    
  Serial.begin(9600);    
  gpsPort.begin(9600);    
  Serial.println(F("gps serial initialize"));    
 
  sim800.begin(9600);    
  Serial.println(F("SIM800A serial initialize"));    
 
  Serial.println(F("Initializing modem..."));    
  modem.init();    
  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();   
  Serial.print(F("Modem: "));   
  Serial.println(modemInfo);    
 
  http_client.setHttpResponseTimeout(10 * 1000);     
}    
 
void loop()    
{
 
  Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));    
  Serial.print(apn);    
  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, user, pass))    
  {    
    Serial.println(F(" fail"));    
    //delay(1000);    
    return;    
  }    
  Serial.println(F(" OK"));    
 
  http_client.connect(FIREBASE_HOST, SSL_PORT);    
 
  while (true) {    
    if (!http_client.connected())    
    {    
      Serial.println();   
      http_client.stop();// Shutdown    
      Serial.println(F("HTTP  not connected"));    
      break;    
    }    
    else    
    {   
      gps_loop();    
    }   
  }   
}   

void PostToFirebase(const char* method, const String & path , const String & data, HttpClient* http)   
{
  String response;   
  int statusCode = 0;    
  http->connectionKeepAlive();    
  String url;   
  if (path[0] != '/')   
  {   
    url = "/";   
  }   
  url += path + ".json";   
  url += "?auth=" + FIREBASE_AUTH;    
  Serial.print("POST:");   
  Serial.println(url);    
  Serial.print("Data:");    
  Serial.println(data);   
 
  String contentType = "application/json";    
  http->put(url, contentType, data);    
  
  statusCode = http->responseStatusCode();    
  Serial.print(F("Status code: "));    
  Serial.println(statusCode);    
  response = http->responseBody();   
  Serial.print(F("Response: "));   
  Serial.println(response);    
  
  if (!http->connected())   
  {   
    Serial.println();   
    http->stop();// Shutdown   
    Serial.println(F("HTTP POST disconnected"));    
  }   
 
}

 void gps_loop()   
{
  boolean newData = false;   
  for (unsigned long start = millis(); millis() - start < 2000;){   
    while (ss.available()){   
      if (tinyGPS.encode(ss.read())){   
        newData = true;   
        break;  
      }  
    }  
  }    
  
  if(true){   
  newData = false;    
  
  String latitude, longitude;   
  
  latitude = String(tinyGPS.location.lat(), 6);    
  longitude = String(tinyGPS.location.lng(), 6);    
     
  
  Serial.print("Latitude= ");    
  Serial.print(latitude);   
  Serial.print(" Longitude= ");     
  Serial.println(longitude);   
      
  String gpsData = "{";   
  gpsData += "\"lat\":" + latitude + ",";   
  gpsData += "\"lng\":" + longitude + "";   
  gpsData += "}";   
  
  PostToFirebase("PATCH", FIREBASE_PATH, gpsData, &http_client);   
    
  }
 
}
```

Comment: This is my output
19:23:44.726 -> gps serial initialize       
19:23:44.726 -> SIM800A serial initialize        
19:23:44.759 -> Initializing modem...        
19:23:44.936 -> Modem: SIM800 R14.18    
19:23:44.936 -> Connecting to internet OK    
19:24:14.571 -> Latitude= 0.000000 Longitude= 0.000000   
19:24:14.667 -> Data:{"lat":0.000000,"lng":0.000000}    
19:24:21.689 -> Status code: 200

Comment: https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/software-serial#listen

Comment: @Juraj Hi, after i add for the listen( ), it can read the data already, but my http is disconnect, means it cannot send the data to the firebase, do you knows what is the problem?

Comment: `listen` clears the receive buffer for SoftwareSerial which stops to listens. this can cause loss of replay from the GSM module

Comment: @Juraj Ouhhh, then  what can I do for this?